# Controlling showAsAction of MenuItem under AppCompat v21 and using a Toolbar

Tags: android-menu

I am trying adopt the v21 AppCompat libraries and leverage the better control of the ActionBar using a Toolbar as described [here](http://antonioleiva.com/material-design-everywhere/) and [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html). But no matter how I modify the menu XML, I can only get the menu items to show up in the overflow area. I would like to see the MenuItem represented as an icon on the Toolbar/ActionBar.

My menu declaration looks like this (note the showAsAction line):

```
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:res-auto="http:/>/schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
    <item android:id="@+id/action_add"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
        android:title="@string/action_add"
        android:orderInCategory="2"
        res-auto:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

I have also tried this (with a slightly different showAsAction line):

```
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:res-auto="http:/>/schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
    <item android:id="@+id/action_add"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
        android:title="@string/action_add"
        android:orderInCategory="2"
        android:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

But the only way I have successfully been able to get the icon to show up on the Toolbar/ActionBar is to force it in code.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    // Try to manually force the item onto the bar instead of allowing it in the overflow
    // for some reason, android is not picking up the setting in the menu declaration
    // using android:showAsAction="always" (even when using the auto-res namespace)
    MenuItem addItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_add);
    MenuCompat.setShowAsAction(addItem, MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
    return true;
}
```

I am using the android.support.v4.view.MenuCompat static methods to achieve this. But I believe I should be able to do this declaratively in the XML. I have tried using both "always" and "ifRoom" but for no effect. I can only assume that the XML attribute is not being picked up.

I guess it is really something simple or related to the fact that I am using the new Toolbar to function as the holder of the menu. The Toolbar layout is very simple:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />
```

and the usage seems quite standard:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Any help would be appreciated. And I am happy to share more of the project content if it helps to get to the bottom of it.